# Polysemy of the /scheduling tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) tag has two unrelated meanings:

- the OS scheduler (task priorities, `sched_getscheduler`, etc.)
- scheduling a program to run at a certain time (cron, atc, etc.)

These should be split. What should be the names of the two tags?

Answer (score 6):

`scheduler` and `scheduling` - the gerund for the latter makes sense with respect to the majority of the question types around `cron` and `at`.

This could be further clarified with the sort of note in the tag wiki that `install` has, for example, where the correct usage is spelled out for new users.

Comment: There is no [tag:installation] ... did you mean [tag:install]?

Comment: @derobert Indeed, I did. Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to leave [scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) for scheduler-related questions and use [cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cron) for cron questions, [at](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/at) for at questions etc...

Comment: This is not very good for askers who are coming from Windows and don't know cron, at, etc. Even beyond that, there is some use for a generic tag about the concept, when the right tool isn't obvious from the question.